# Spring Gateway 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'DOMAIN, *', but only one is allowed

Tags: cors, spring-cloud-gateway

While trying to connect a React frontend to the backend through the Spring Cloud Gateway version(2021.0.5), CORS throws an error due to Multiples Values. CORS is configured only in the Gateway; backend services do not have CORS configured. We tried several things, such as configuring CORS via Bean, as well YML file, but it did not solve the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

YML configuration

```
spring:
application:
    name: ecs_api_gateway
cloud:
    gateway:
        default-filters:
          - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, RETAIN_UNIQUE
        globalcors:
          cors-configurations:
            '[/**]':
                allowed-origins: "http://ayc.org"
                allowed-methods: "*"
                allowed-headers: "*"
                allow-credentials: true
```

Comment: Did you find the anwser? I have the same problem and the solution I find on internet does not work for me, my yml file is the identical yours.